# Toggling all <li>s until next <li class="nav-header"> and filtering nav-list in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an fluid.html example from Twitter Bootstrap - the nav-list on the left is what is giving me a headache for last few hours. I need to do either or both of these things:

1. Filter the nav-list - more or less what this does: http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/javascript/how-to-build-a-fast-simple-list-filter-with-jquery/ - while it works nicely on this site, I can't get it to filter elements in nav-list in Bootstrap without breaking its look.
2. Toggle all `<li>`s until next `<li class="nav-header">` by clicking on one of the `<li class="nav-header">` elements. So if I have:

   - Category 1

     - Link 1
     - Link 2
     - Link 3
   - Category 2

     - Link 4
     - Link 5
     - Link 6

...clicking on Category 1 should toggle links 1, 2 and 3, and clicking on Category 2 should toggle links 4, 5 and 6 only. I've tried jQuery Collapse plugin, but it broke nav-list style. I've also tried to toggle `<div>` in which I had all `<li>`s between `<li class="nav-header">`s - but it also broke the nav-list style. I had an idea to toggle all `<li>`s with the same id, but I don't know how to do it with jQuery or plain JavaScript.

Any idea how to do either or both of these things? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if there's a child `<ul>`, and then toggle it on click with jQuery.

```
<script>
    $('li').on('click', function() {
        $(this).children('ul').toggle();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In code, the entire list is shown this way: http://pastie.org/private/ymgkwlojimfyoomrellpg - so this won't work here. :(

Comment: Well I couldn't account for that since you didn't post any code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've finally fixed the list filtering with jQuery and the first example. The problem was, jQuery was loaded at the end of the document, and the script required it to be loaded before the form. So, works :)